# How to convert signal name (string) to signal code?

Tags: c++, linux, posix, signals

I am writing a program that reads the name of the signal (e.g. SIGSTOP, SIGKILL etc) as a string from the command line and calls the kill() system call to send the signal. I was wondering if there is a simple way to convert the string to signal codes (in signal.h).

Currently, I'm doing this by writing my own map that looks like this:

```
signal_map["SIGSTOP"] = SIGSTOP;
signal_map["SIGKILL"] = SIGKILL;
....
```

But its tedious to write this for all signals. So, I was looking for a more elegant way, if it exists.

Comment: But in theory once you have the map, the tedium ends, right? That seems like a reasonable approach (though if other with more experience know of a better way, you should listen to them!)

Comment: kill(1) does exactly what you're suggesting. http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/proc/sig.c?view=markup

Comment: @jamessan

why didn't you post it as an Answer?
Is that cross-os safe?

Comment: @jamessan i need signal code for other reasons than just feeding kill()

Comment: @blu3bird: I didn't say you needed to use kill.  I'm saying that the implementation of kill does exactly what you're talking about (although in C).

Comment: @seppo0010: It's cross-os safe in that it's using the constants defined by the OS's header files instead of assuming the number value.  The part that needs care is whether certain signals are defined at all.

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if that is what you are loking for, but:
strerror() converts a error code to the error message,
similar strsignal() converts a signal to the signal message.

```
fprintf(stdout, "signal 9: %s\n", strsignal(9));
fprintf(stdout, "errno 60: %s\n", strerror(60));

Output:
signal 9: Killed
errno 60: Device not a stream
```

Comment: ah well i just re-read your question and your converting from string to nr, so my answer will not be helpful :)

Comment: But it can be helpful - just combine it with OP's map. Instead of filling in the map manually, use a `for ( n=1; n < NSIG; ++n ) signal_map[strsignal(n)] = n;`. The only nuance is that `strsignal` does not return "canonical" signal names, e.g. instead of SIGTERM it returns TERMINATE (in my Linux, at least).

Comment: @Chris...thanks for letting me know of strsignal() function. Thats interesting.

Comment: This should have been accepted as the answer. Doing so would  help future searchers

Answer (score 7):

You can use a command line like this

```
kill -l \
        | sed 's/[0-9]*)//g' \
        | xargs -n1 echo \
        | awk '{ print "signal_map[\"" $0 "\"] = " $0 ";" }'
```

It will write your map for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using C++0x you can use initializer lists to make this more simple:

```
const std::map<std::string, signal_t> signal_map{ 
   {"SIGSTOP", SIGSTOP },
   {"SIGKILL", SIGKILL },
   ... 
};
```

This get's you the map at less code to write. If you want to you could also some preprocessor magic to get the code even simpler and avoid writing the name multiple times. But most often abusing the preprocessor just leads to less usable code not better code. (Note that preprocessor magic can still be used if you decide not to use C++0x and keep your way).