# Given a string with a signal name, how do I get the appropriate signal number?

Tags: c, signals

`sys_signame` was [suggested by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16509837/1561811), and it's exactly what I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem to be supported by (some) Linux distros. Is there a more standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* kill -l is specified by POSIX. You could fork and exec it and parse its output.
I know of no more standards-compliant method, I'm afraid.

Comment: Is it safe to assume there's a `kill` in `$PATH` somewhere?

Comment: There's a kill built into all shells I'm aware of, to avoid the situation whereby the kernel's process table is full, so the shell is unable to fork(2) in order to order exec(2) an external kill in order to free up a process table entry.

Comment: [`dash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell) doesn't seem to have a `kill` builtin.

Comment: Dash 0.5.7-3 from unstable/armel has a builtin kill (I just checked). Which version do you have?

Comment: 0.5.7-stable, from Homebrew (which gets it from [gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert](http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/))

Answer (score 1):

You might have to build a map manually. This thread might help.

[How to convert signal name (string) to signal code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990093/how-to-convert-signal-name-string-to-signal-code)

Comment: Also these names will not change unexpectedly (nor the numbers) so manual map should be good enough.

Comment: But they might vary across OS or CPU architecture. see `man 7 signal` on Linux