# Signal sender conversion

Tags: c++, linux, signals, system-calls

I'm attempting to write a program in C++ that sends signals to another one the same way you would do with the `kill` commmand in Linux, but it seems I'm running into some conversion problems. As I see it, I can't just pass signals as strings (`SIGINT`, `SIGUSR1`, etc.) through the terminal and convert them easily inside the program. Neither was I able to accomplish my goal by passing them as their correspondent `int`s (2,30, etc.) and using a system call directly. Here's my code:

## Passing signals as int types

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    int signal = atoi(argv[2]); //passing signals directly as int 

    cout << signal << endl;

    int error = kill(pid, signal);

    if(error !=0)
        cout << "Error sending signal to catcher program."<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

## output

```
~$./signal_sender 5977 2
2
Error sending signal to catcher program.
```

As for when I tried using strings, I couldn't find a conversion that worked properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the `errno` you get from `kill()`?

Comment: `ESRCH        3  /* No such process */` So I guess I was sending signals to the wrong pid. By correcting it, I got it working through ints, but still no luck when passing strings.

Comment: See my full answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert signal name (string) to signal code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990093/how-to-convert-signal-name-string-to-signal-code)

Answer (score 1):

The two most likely causes for the error are:

- there is no process with the given `pid`;
- you don't have permissions to send the signal to the process.

To figure out which it is, print out and examine the value of `errno` after the call to `kill()` has failed. See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) for the list of `errno` values you can get from `kill()`.

As to converting signal names to numbers, see [How to convert signal name (string) to signal code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990093/how-to-convert-signal-name-string-to-signal-code) (In a nutshell, you will most likely have to have your own table of signal names and corresponding numbers.)

Comment: It was the first one. I got errno #3 (No such process). Seems it works when passing signal int codes directly, but still no luck with string conversion. Thanks for the help.